# What's the equivalent of top -H -p <pid> on OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, top, ps

I need to monitor the CPU usage of threads created by a given process.

In *nix one can use `top -H -p <pid>`, but that not available in OS X.

An equivalent of `ps -eLo pid,ppid,lwp,nlwp,osz,rss,ruser,pcpu,stime,etime,args` would also suffice.

Answer (score 3):

Tree view in `htop` is similar (see picture). You can install `htop` with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/), then toggle tree view with <kbd>F5</kbd>. To keep a process and its threads from jumping around on updates, you can select the parent process and use <kbd>F</kbd> to keep it in place.

[image: htop]